# integral of series multiplied by function rules

Tags: power-series, fourier-series

I have been asked the following question, and I wonder why my answer incorrect:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot cos(kx))$$

what is the value of the following integral?
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cdot cos(2x) dx$$

(long story short: the answer should be $4\pi$, but I get for some reason $0$)

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot cos(kx)) \cdot cos(2x)dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot cos(kx)\cdot cos(2x))dx $

(cosine's multiplication trigonometric identity):

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot(cos(kx+2x)+cos(kx-2x)))dx $

(integral of sum $\equiv$ sum of integral):

$\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot \frac{1}{2})\cdot\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(cos(kx+2x)+cos(kx-2x))dx $

$\rightarrow$ $\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot \frac{1}{2})\cdot (\frac{sin(kx + 2x)}{k + 2} + \frac{sin(kx - 2x)}{k - 2} )|_{x = -\pi}^{x= \pi}$

$(2\cdot \frac{sin(k\pi + 2\pi)}{k+2} + 2\cdot \frac{sin(k\pi - 2\pi)}{k-2}) \equiv (2\cdot \frac{0}{k+2} + 2\cdot \frac{0}{k-2}) \equiv 0$

$\rightarrow$  $\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k^2\cdot \frac{1}{2})\cdot 0 = 0$

I will be glad to know where am I wrong (my guess I couldn't "take out" the sum from the integral), and if there is an answer that doesn't forces me to write down explicitly $f(x)$.

Comment: These are finite sums, so you can certainly interchange the order of the sum and the integral

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have $k-2$ in  the denominator.  This is BAD, because $k=2$ is one of the values in your sum, so you have "divide by zero" in there.

---

You should have computed the $k=2$ term separately.

When $k=2$, we have
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(k^2\cdot \cos(kx)\cdot \cos(2x))\;dx
\\=
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(4\cdot \cos(2x)\cdot \cos(2x))\;dx
\\=
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} 4\cos^2(2x)\;dx = 4\pi .
$$

The rest of the terms yield $0$, as you correctly computed.

Comment: Got your comment, thanks. Anyway if this is the situation, what should have I done instead?